# Getting TLE in hackerearth

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, primes

When i submiting this code at hackerearth i am getting TLE.

Any suggestions how can i optimise this 
Code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int checkPrime(int);

int main() {
int a, b,
    reminder,sum=0,n;

    scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);

    while(a <= b) {
        n = a;
        sum = 0;
        reminder = 0;

        while (n > 0) {
        reminder = n % 10;
        sum += reminder;
        n = n / 10;
        }

        if(sum > 1 && checkPrime(sum) == 1 && checkPrime(a) == 1) {
            printf("%d ",a);  
        }

        ++a;
    }

return 0;
}

int checkPrime(int p) {

int i,flag=1;

for(i=2; i <= p / 2; i++){
    if(p%i == 0)  {
        flag = 0;
        break;  
    }
}

return flag;

}
```

[Here is the problem i coded for](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/complexity-analysis/time-and-space-complexity/practice-problems/algorithm/prime-ministers-number/description/)

And how can i analysis this code and get
Time complexity.

Comment: and what is TLE ?

Comment: @u__ Time Limit Exceeded. And that's the problem that needs to be solved. The task at face value is usually not so difficult as finding an effiecient solution.

Comment: Typically being able to derive the time complexity for a specific algorithm is very useful to improve it.

Comment: There are plenty of examples on SO of more efficient prime algorithms. For example, why are you checking every even divisor? 2 is the only even prime. That change alone will halve the run time.

Comment: Please give your question a more descriptive title, so that other users with a similar problem can find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `checkprime` function takes a lot of runtime. It runs for `N/2` operations.

You are running this for all the numbers, so you are running for `N*N/2` operations, which is too much.

I would suggest that you use a better method of generating the primes. Take a look at [the Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: Even checking all odd numbers (and 2) up to `sqrt(N)` would probably do the trick. Or all `6n+1` and `6n-1` if you want to be fancy.

Comment: Thanks all for your kindness :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some primitive ways like this one for instance, looping through the odd numbers and some more optimizations

```
int isPrime ( int n )
{
    if (n <= 1) return 0; // zero and one are not prime
    unsigned int i;
    for (i=2; i*i<=n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

`Seive` is kind of *over-kill*, in your case ( if you are not taking in to consideration your memory requirements ) because the range could be very very large `1000000`  you might want to use some sort of bitmap to generate the Seive.

here is a very loosely written Idea of how to generate and use Seive.

```
char *seive;

void generate_seive( int n )
{
        seive = calloc( 1, n );
        if( !seive )
        {
                printf("E...");
                exit(0);
        }

        // Generate Seive 
        for( int i = 2; i < n ; i ++)
        {
                if( seive[i] == 1 )
                        continue;
                // Essentially mark all primes as 0 and
                // non-primes as 1's
                seive[i] = 0;
                for( int j = i + i ; j < n ; j += i )
                        seive[j] = 1;
        }
}

int main()
{
        generate_seive(100);

        // Iterating through the generated Seive 
        // should do
        for( int i = 2; i < 100 ; i ++ )
                if( seive[i] == 0 )
                        printf("%d\n", i);
        return 0;
}
```